# Which is the oldest known reference to a 7 day week in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture

I thought of this question after reading about [day-wise restrictions on shaving/haircut](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14189/290)

These weekly day-wise restrictions must have started after a 7 day week was established.

Which is the oldest known reference to a 7 day week (or a particular day of the week) in Hindu scriptures?

(Note - [This question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15646/absence-of-names-of-days-in-scriptures-why) lists some (not all) scriptures with references to `the week` or `weekdays`, but it  does it mention which one is the oldest)

Comment: @TheDestroyer thanks for link. There are some mentions in that question's answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15646/absence-of-names-of-days-in-scriptures-why) but I am looking for a slightly different question. I am asking what is the "oldest known" reference to a week. The people in that thread do not attempt dating the scriptures they are referring to. I think this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Ok. I reopened it. You can edit the details with it. But still i think it is duplicate as dating of scriptures is never accurate as they are transmitted through oral tradition.

Comment: @TheDestroyer yes, but at least we can know the latest limit on the date (for example at least before 100 CE)

Comment: user13107 If your question is different, make modifications in the question don't just say it is not a duplicate. I don't see any modifications after closing and before reopening. If you are looking for dating of scriptures, then it would be a different question which is already asked. [When exactly were the puranas were written?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19804/when-exactly-were-the-puranas-were-written) cc @TheDestroyer

Comment: @Sinister i had already added a note in the question text (expanded it just now). If it is your claim that it is duplicate, then you should tell why it's duplicate.

Comment: You added a note that this question mentions and now you've edited it that it doesn't mention the date. You can ask the answerer in comments when it was written or you may put a bounty on the post I linked(if you feel it is urgent). But the main intention of the post is dating the scriptures. Isn't it? That was asked in the post I linked. Now, you should mention how your post is different from the linked post. Adding a note doesn't differentiate a duplicate and a original post. Modification in the content of the body does.

Comment: @Sinister you are assuming that Puranas is the correct answer. What if there are other known ancient documents that refer to weekdays? That possibility is not covered if we treat this question as duplicate of those two questions combined. (i will later add conclusion of this discussion to main post)